# Can I newJob on a class and also set some values?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

The usage of newJob is like the following:

```
newJob(ConnectorScheduler.class)
```

But I also want to set some spring JdbcTemplate on the instance of ConnectorScheduler, is that doable?

Basically I want to do

```
job=new ConnectorScheduler();
job.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
newJob(job);
```

Comment: I saw that you're trying to use Quartz with Spring, why don't you take some time to read the Spring documentation on this topic? :)
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you can pass parameters to jobs (and triggers), but in Quartz you must use the [JobDataMap](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/index.html?org/quartz/JobDataMap.html) structure that works like so:

```
job=new ConnectorScheduler();
job.getJobDataMap().put("param1", "123");
newJob(job);
```

For numerical (and other non-string values) you can use:

```
job.getJobDataMap().putAsString("param1", 123);
```

Comment: sorry what if I want to use some object instead of int or string etc. Looks like getJobDataMap can only use string/int.

Comment: You do not want to store non-primitive objects in the JobDataMap to avoid all sorts of serialization issues. Please refer to http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/best-practices for details. If you want to store non-primitive data types, you can often represent them as strings (e.g. JSON, XML,...). Then you can easily handle object versioning in your serializers/deserializers, e.g. by embedding the version number in the string.

Comment: The problem is in the job I need to access jdbcTemplate, so there is no easy way instead of doing many code to create the jdbcTemplate?

Comment: If you still insist you want to store non-primitive objects in the JobDataMap regardless of what has been said above, you can do so by using the put(String,Object) method. Please note that JobDataMap implements Map<String,Object>. BTW: storing non-string objects in the JobDataMap will prevent you from easily modifying the JobDataMap from Quartz management GUIs (e.g.  https://www.quartzdesk.com - I am the founder here).

Comment: AFAIK JdbcTemplate contains a reference to a DataSource and a DataSource is definitely not a serializable object so you will never be able to persist a JdbcTemplate instance in the JobDataMap unless you are using a RAMJobStore (in which case the serialization obviously does not happen).

Comment: If the above answers your question, please consider accepting the answer or provide additional comments so that we can help you. Thank you.